# When JHipster create the dummy data starting from JDL?

Tags: java, jhipster

I'm new to JHipster and I'm doing some experiment.
I created my fist JHipster App and imported the "default" JDL that can be downloaded from here: [JDL Studio](https://start.jhipster.tech/jdl-studio/) (without any modification).

After the import, I see my entity filled with some demo data and
some `csv` file has been created under `config/liquidbase/data` with the same info.

I checked the `jhipster-jdl.jh` file and there is no data specification there.

I don't understand where that data is created and what is the logic that allows creating that dummy data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The values are generated by [Faker.js](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/) in the [`table.csv` template](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/d3ec0c0b69630632b854ede88121b0c4366d4a16/generators/entity-server/templates/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/data/table.csv.ejs).  They are based on the column name, and are not configurable at this point.

If you don't want the data to be inserted into the database, you can remove the `faker` context from the config in [`application-dev.yml`](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/07c54b42ac7b53ba18f13b23f2f577e0a3d26ca2/src/main/resources/config/application-dev.yml#L59-L61)